# git annex with bup

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-annex

Can any one tell me how to use git annex with bup.

```
git annex initremote mybup type=bup encryption=none buprepo=example.com:/big/mybup
```

is not working for me.
if I type

```
git annex
```

it will list all commands, but in this initremote command is not there. what could be the problem.

Answer (score 7):

bup support was added to git-annex in April 2011. You probably have a rather older version, as the initremote command was added around the same time. If you're using Debian stable, there is a backport of a current git-annex you can upgrade to easily. Or you can install a newer version by hand pretty easily.

Comment: I consider this answer as coming from a deity :)